# How to convert - into + to create a conjugate of imaginary part?

Tags: c#, .net, complex-numbers

I'm trying to overload a `/` (divide) operator to divide two complex numbers. How do I invert the polarity of imaginary part in a complex number such that it acts a conjugate of complex number hence the distributive multiplication of the complex number and its conjugate can be carried out.
For example:

Dividing these two complex numbers:

```
(6 + 3i) / (7 - 5i)

[(6 + 3i)*(7 + 5i)] / [(7 - 5i)*(7 + 5i)] //have to create conjugate by inverting signs

7(6 + 3i) + 5i(6 + 3i) / 7(7 - 5i) + 5i(7 + 5i)

Where i² = -1

(42 + 51i + 15) / (49 + 25)

(27 + 5i) / (74)  => (27/74) + (51i/74)
```

My current code is this and is not yielding correct results

`rhscomplexnumber` stands for right hand side complex number `(6 + 3i)`

`lhscomplexnumber` stands for left hand side complex number `(7 - 5i)`

I am multiplying the -ve imaginary part of `rhscomplexnumber` with `-1` to generate a +ve conjugate of same magnitude.

```
public class Complex
{
    public double Real { get; set; }
    public double Imaginary { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Real > 0)
            return Real.ToString() + "+i" + Imaginary.ToString();
        else
            return Real.ToString() + "-i" + Math.Abs(Imaginary).ToString();
    }

    public static Complex operator / (Complex lhscomplexnumber, Complex rhscomplexnumber)
    {
        Complex result = new Complex();

        double NumeratorReal = (rhscomplexnumber.Real * lhscomplexnumber.Real) + (-1*((-1 * rhscomplexnumber.Imaginary) * (lhscomplexnumber.Imaginary)));
        double NumeratorImag = (rhscomplexnumber.Real * lhscomplexnumber.Imaginary) + ((-1 * rhscomplexnumber.Imaginary) * (lhscomplexnumber.Real));
        double DenominatorReal = (rhscomplexnumber.Real * lhscomplexnumber.Real) + (-1*((-1 * rhscomplexnumber.Imaginary) * (lhscomplexnumber.Imaginary)));
        double DenominatorImag = (rhscomplexnumber.Real * lhscomplexnumber.Imaginary) + (-1 * rhscomplexnumber.Imaginary * lhscomplexnumber.Real);
        result.Real = NumeratorReal / DenominatorReal;
        result.Real = Math.Round(result.Real, 1);
        result.Imaginary = NumeratorImag / DenominatorReal;
        result.Imaginary = Math.Round(result.Imaginary, 1);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: i would use a nuget package - maybe these people (https://www.extremeoptimization.com) can help?

Comment: i must do it using no external packages.

Comment: @learningtocode - You've way over-complicated this. Try implementing `static Complex operator *(Complex a, Complex b)`, `static Complex Conjugate(Complex a)`, and `static Complex operator /(Complex a, double b)`, then `static Complex operator /(Complex a, Complex b)` becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
public class Complex
{
    public double Real { get; set; }
    public double Imaginary { get; set; }

    public static Complex operator *(Complex a, Complex b) =>
        new Complex()
        {
            Real = a.Real * b.Real - a.Imaginary * b.Imaginary,
            Imaginary = a.Real * b.Imaginary + a.Imaginary * b.Real,
        };

    public static Complex Conjugate(Complex a) =>
            new Complex() { Real = a.Real, Imaginary = -a.Imaginary };

    public static Complex operator /(Complex a, double b) =>
            new Complex() { Real = a.Real / b, Imaginary = a.Imaginary / b };

    public static Complex operator /(Complex a, Complex b) =>
            a * Conjugate(b) / (b * Conjugate(b)).Real;
}
```

---

If you want to go for bonus points, try this:

```
public struct Complex : IEquatable<Complex>
{
    public double R { get; private set; }
    public double I { get; private set; }

    public static Complex Create(double r, double i) => new Complex() { R = r, I = i };

    public static Complex operator +(Complex a, Complex b) => Complex.Create(a.R + b.R, a.I + b.I);
    public static Complex operator -(Complex a, Complex b) => Complex.Create(a.R - b.R, a.I - b.I);
    public static Complex operator *(Complex a, Complex b) => Complex.Create(a.R * b.R - a.I * b.I, a.R * b.I + a.I * b.R);
    public static Complex operator /(Complex a, Complex b) => a * b.Conjugate() / (b * b.Conjugate()).R;
    public static Complex operator /(Complex a, double b) => Complex.Create(a.R / b, a.I / b);

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Complex)
            return Equals((Complex)obj);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Complex obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<double>.Default.Equals(R, obj.R)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<double>.Default.Equals(I, obj.I)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<double>.Default.GetHashCode(R);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<double>.Default.GetHashCode(I);
        return hash;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{R}{(I >= 0 ? "+" : "")}{I}";
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Complex left, Complex right)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null))
        {
            return object.ReferenceEquals(right, null);
        }

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Complex left, Complex right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}

public static class ComplexEx
{
    public static Complex Conjugate(this Complex a) => Complex.Create(a.R, -a.I);
}
```

Comment: shiny, i can't be sure how most of this works but i've been looking for examples of complex numbers in something other than mathjax for a while!

Comment: @ocæon - This is where coding is cool. Small parts that do simple tasks, composed together to make the complex whole work simply.

Comment: @ocæon - And I love the use of the word "Shiny". Browncoats unite!